# Nagios notifications - Notifications

Tags: nagios

We use two templates one called 24x7-critical and one non-critical.

The 24x7 alert 24x7, the non critical alert during business hours.

Some of the services that are non-critical alert someone that is not interested in those particular services.

I have tried in the service definition

define service....
...
contact !joe 
(No other users are defined here)
...

But that doesn't work. What is the correct way to stop one user getting these alerts?

Answer (score 1):

Use templates for the services, one for crit and one for non-crit.

To each template, assign appropriate notification_period and contacts/contact_groups.